# I have problems with print to next page

Tags: vb.net

I get the first page to work but it does not print the next page, if I have more rows or if I space it out more to get it to print on the next print page it doesn't do that.

The code that I use.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

        Dim Head As Integer = 0
        Dim List As Integer

        Head += 30
        For List = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        Next
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Pocket bok collection", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 20), Brushes.Black, 250, Head)
        Head += 40
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Pocket Serie Name", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 50, Head)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Single/Double", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, Head)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Pocket Nr", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 200, Head)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Year", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 300, Head)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Bought Date", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 450, Head)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Cost", New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 550, Head)
        List += 60

        If List > 1000 Then
            e.HasMorePages = True

        End If

        For Each Itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 50, List)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(1).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, List)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(2).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 200, List)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(3).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 300, List)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(4).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 450, List)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(5).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times new roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 550, List)
            List += 50

        Next

        e.HasMorePages = False

        Exit Sub


    End Sub
```

What am i missing or is something not right, i have search and watched but can't find why it is not working.

Comment: What's the point of having `Exit Sub` as the last line in the method? When it gets to that line it's going to exit the method naturally anyway so that achieves nothing. This is an example of why you should figure out the logic first and then write code to specifically implement that logic. There should be no code that doesn't directly correspond to something in that logic.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `e.HasMorePages` to `False` at the end of the method no matter what happens, so it will never print a second page. You would have seen that if you had debugged your code, as you are required to do before asking a question.

`e.HasMorePages` is `False` by default and you should set it to `True` if and only if there is more data to print. You have an `If` block to do that. There are still other issues with your code but that will address the immediate issue you have asked about here.

Comment: If I set it to e.HasMorePages to True, it works until it is about to print, then it counts up the pages until I cancel it, yes, I also run the program in vb:s test and the debug should be active but does not get any indications of errors or it Break/stop.

Comment: @Joachim, as I said in the answer, there are other issues with your code but the information I provided addresses the question you actually asked. Make the change and accept the answer. If you need to solve some other issue then you should post another question that includes the specific information relevant to that. At SO you are required to address one specific issue at a time.